# What is the reason for empty cloudwatch streams?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have noticed that cloudwatch streams are empty and are generating at no particular pattern from lambda. The lambda is configured to run concurrently. I am not able to figure out why are there few empty streams.
Example below -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Log streams that are older than retention period will continue showing on "Log Groups/Log Streams" section but when you access it to check the logs events, these would not be available due to retention period.

So this could be your scenario. You can compare the "Last event time" of the Log stream with the Log group retention period.
[image]

Comment: Nope. The log streams are generated just now and I see them empty.

Comment: The lambda function has enough permissions? (logs:CreateLogGroup, logs:CreateLogStream and logs:PutLogEvents)

Comment: Yes. It has other log streams which are not empty.

Comment: Any update on this thread, I'm facing the same issue in my AWS account.

Comment: It seems the log events can not be older than 14 days ago when you use putLogEvents https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html